# TeamCity administration website not reachable

Tags: linux, centos, java, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity and I was trying to get it up and running on CentOS server. I am having issues with the control website to showup.

Following are the steps I have taken to setup TeamCity.

I have downloaded latest version of TeamCity: https://download.jetbrains.com/teamcity/TeamCity-2019.1.2.tar.gz and extracted it:

```
tar xpf TeamCity-2019.1.2.tar.gz
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel  

set the environment variables

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64

cd /var/www/apps/teamcity/TeamCity/bin

sudo su
./teamcity-server.sh stop
./teamcity-server.sh start
```

Here is the web root folder for TeamCity : /var/www/apps/teamcity/TeamCity/webapps

```
ps -ef | grep java

netstat -anp | grep java

[root@xxx webapps]# netstat -anp | grep java
tcp6 0 0 :::8111 :::* LISTEN 1807/java
tcp6 0 0 :::9090 :::* LISTEN 10572/java
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8105 :::* LISTEN 1807/java
tcp6 0 0 xx.xx.xxx.xx:yyyy xx.xx.xxx.xx:yyyy ESTABLISHED 1551/java
unix 2 [ ] STREAM CONNECTED 1787115 1807/java
unix 2 [ ] STREAM CONNECTED 1787112 1807/java
unix 2 [ ] STREAM CONNECTED 1261444 10572/java
unix 2 [ ] STREAM CONNECTED 17997 1551/java
```

I am unable to reach to the site http:IPAddress:8111 to reach teamcity. What can I check to see the reason for the site(http:IPAddress:8111) not reachable from my Windows laptop to the TeamCity running on CentOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with tcp6, once tcp6 was disabled, this issue got resolved.